# Using boxcutter on Instances

Tags: modeling, instances

I've been creating a group of buildings (rough stage, just rectangles) as clones with ALT-D, and wanted the edit one of them, to have the changes applied to all. With normal edit mode functions that worked well, but when I used boxcutter on the object, the changes didn't apply to the other instances - and the box-cluttered object got disconnected from the other instances. Could not figure out how to fix this.

Any advise? How to apply boxcutter on one instance with having the changes get applied to the rest? Much appreciate your help.

Comment: One thing you can do: Select all the unchanged objects (the ones you want to have the same mesh as the object you changed with the box-cutter). Then Shift select the changed object, press Ctrl + L, and choose Object Data. The mesh data will be copied to the other objects, similar to using Alt + D but retroactively.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift reply - much appreciated. If the various instances have different sizes, does that work as well? or will the command then apply and equal the entire mesh size / dimension across the instances? The idea is to add details to the buildings while maintaining their different shapes.

Comment: I think it's helpful to see mesh data and object transform data apart from each other An object is a container for a mesh, but you can also see it as a non destructive modifier. If you scale an Object it gets stretched, but the mesh (and mesh data) hasn't changed. Press Alt+ S (revert scale) and Alt+ R (revert rotation) and an object changed in Object Mode will look like the initial mesh again. Press Ctrl + A > All Transforms however, and you will change the mesh into what you see (like applying a modifier) and reset object transforms.So it should work for you. Hope that makes sense : )

Comment: Thanks so much - very much appreciate your support. I'll figure this out. Thanks!